# call vbscript from HTML event handler

Tags: vbscript

I have a dropdown list that calls a vbscript.The issue is that when I try to get the value of the drop down list I get "object doesnt support property" or "method error".

```
<select onchange='callMe()' id='selectMe'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='3'>3</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Sub callMe()
MsgBox(selectMe.value)
End Sub
</SCRIPT>
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction please

Comment: You've tagged this question vb.net but the code looks like old fashioned client side VBScript. What sort of solution are you working on?

Comment: I tried your example in IE9 and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/wXPfN/

Comment: Hello Mark. It works intermittently for me. But sometimes it fails. I am using IE8.

Comment: have you tried `<select language="VBScript" onchange="callMe()" id="selectMe">` or `<select name="selectMe">` and rename the `Sub` to `selectMe_OnChange`? [reference](http://library.thinkquest.org/16728/content/scripting/events.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use W3Schools reference on the [HTML DOM Select Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_select.asp).

- Use selectMe.options
- Use selectMe.selectedIndex

When using VBScript, you will get implicit events base on the object's *id* so you don't need to explicitly call them (i.e. selectMe_onchange). I've reworked your example as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>VBScript Select event</title>
    <script LANGUAGE="VBScript">
      Sub selectMe_onchange
      MsgBox selectMe.options(selectMe.selectedIndex).text
      End Sub
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id='selectMe'>
      <option value='1'>1</option>
      <option value='3'>3</option>
      <option value='2'>2</option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is old but I ultimately ended up doing this. Thanks Stephen

Answer (score 1):

you can do what Stephan Quan has posted as it does not matter where in page eg. head or body it is placed

in the following examples you would need to be in the body as it required for select element to be created prior to using

`' if you just need to display

msgbox document.getElementById("selectMe").value
  ' if you need to do something with the value 
dim somevariable 
somevariable = document.getElementById("selectMe").value`

in the second example somevariable would contain the value attribute from selected option